# ¿Cómo conectar API en PHP con React AXIOS?

Tags: php, axios

Quiero conectar mi Api con Axios pero me manda un error en los Headers y CORS

```
const loginWithEmailPassword = async(idUser, password) => {

        console.log(idUser, password);

        const headers = {
            'idUser': idUser,
            'password': password
        }

        try {

            const response = await backendApi.post("login/", '', { headers: headers });
            console.log(response);

            dispatch(checkingCredencials());
            console.log(status);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(':(');
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
```

En PHP tengo estos Header

```
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la consola me devuelve lo siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si falte agregar algún header como tal en el backend, cualquier ayuda es recibida.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta como mandas los headers, los tendrías que mandar de esta forma:

```
const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
};
```

y tu código debería ser algo así:

```
const loginWithEmailPassword = async(idUser, password) => {

const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
};

const url = "login/";  // Reemplaza con tu URL
const data = {
   idUser, 
   password
   // Ojo si tus variables se llaman igual que la propiedad del objeto 
   //en JavaScript lo puedes enviar con el mismo nombre para evitar idUser: idUser
};
        try {

            const response = await backendApi.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
            console.log(response);
// Resto de tu código
```

Si no funciona, deberías fijarte si existe alguna configuración de permisos (CORS) en tu proyecto.

aquí te dejo la documentación sobre el estandar CORS
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Sólo para pruebas locales

.htaccess

```
# permitir cualquier origen
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# permitir estos headers
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
# permitir estos métodos
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: en el ejemplo particular tendrías que agregar los custom headers `idUser, password` a los allowed